# How to convert int to minutes in sql for mathematical operation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, sum

I have a value of 1045 (assumed as 10:45 am) in my table column which I wanted to sum it up with another column like 1335 (assumed as 13:35 pm)

I know i can't sum it up directly as it will give a wrong time format output like 2380 (assumed as 23:80 pm , where there's no such thing)

So i net to convert it into minute and then only do the normal mathematical operation.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you master

Comment: What does it mean to sum 10:45am and 13:35pm?

Comment: Hi Oli, I wanted to find total hours, so adding it directly without proper formatting will cause an error 

So i need to convert the string from 1045 to 10:45 with (colon in between then convert it to minute then only i can sum it)

Comment: Can you give an example with one row of the table and the calculation you want to perform and the result? I understand wanting to convert a number stored as 1045 into the time 10:45 but when you say you want to "add the number 1335 to that time" I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: adding colon will make it string not int, so what i suggest you is to take string from start. I can provide a bit long but simplest code i can think of for getting the exact addition of your time. If u agree to use string then reply. Or yeah you can convert it into int atlast but you need it to be in string for conversion

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if the sum was (as in your case) greater than 24 hours?  Do you use the modulo (the hours part) or is the day part meaningful?

As you say, take the first two characters, cast as an integer, multiply by 60 and add to the integer cast of the 2nd pair of characters.  Divide by 1440 to get the day fraction.

Alternatively, insert a ':' into the 3rd place and use a string-to-time function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the result should be 2420:

You can do this with a series of integer divisons and modulo operations:

```
set @a=1045;
set @b=1335;
SELECT ((((@a DIV 100) * 60) + @a MOD 100 + ((@b DIV 100) * 60) + @b MOD 100) DIV 60) * 100 +
```

(((@a DIV 100) * 60) + @a MOD 100 + ((@b DIV 100) * 60) + @b MOD 100) MOD 60;

Explanation in single steps:

```
-- gives us the value of @a interpreted as minutes: 645
SELECT 'minutes a' as description, ((@a DIV 100) * 60) + @a MOD 100 as a

-- gives us the value of @b interpreted as minutes: 1815
SELECT 'minutes b', ((@b DIV 100) * 60) + @b MOD 100

-- gives us the sum of those minutes
SELECT 'a + b', ((@a DIV 100) * 60) + @a MOD 100 + ((@b DIV 100) * 60) + @b MOD 100

-- to convert back to HH:mm
SELECT 'a + b in HH:mm', ((((@a DIV 100) * 60) + @a MOD 100 + ((@b DIV 100) * 60) + @b MOD 100) DIV 60) * 100 +
```

(((@a DIV 100) * 60) + @a MOD 100 + ((@b DIV 100) * 60) + @b MOD 100) MOD 60;

See a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e21f1/1)

But these complicated calculations wouldn't be needed, if you would use the proper data type, probably [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a thing you must consider:

Imagine you want to add `20` to `1045`; the result would be `1065` (which cannot be converted to a proper time without some tricks) instead of `1105` (which is surely what you intended).

There are two possible solutions:

1. Convert things "by hand" to quantities that can be added.
2. Use `unix_timestamp()`

The first solution wouuld involve creating a function that converts dates to integers and hours to fractions (sort of Microsoft's style)... this is a cumbersome and prone-to-error approach.

The second option is far more reliable, because:

1. It is a MySQL built-in function
2. It converts dates (and times) to numbers with a predefined epoch: Any date or datetime is defined in UNIX-Time as the number of seconds ellapsed since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`... and you can add this sort of numbers anyway you want.

So, for example, if you wanted to add 13 hours to `2014-07-06 08:00:00' , you'd have something like this:

```sql
select 
    @d := '2014-08-06 08:00:00',  -- Storing the value in the @d temp variable
    unix_timestamp(@d),  -- Converting @d to UNIX time
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(@d) + 13 * (60*60))  -- Adding 13 hours 
                                                      -- (13 * 60 * 60 seconds) to @d 
                                                      -- and converting it back
                                                      -- to DATETIME
;
```

---

Of course, there's a simpler approach. If you want to add some interval to a date or time, you can use the `date_add()` function:

```sql
select @d := '2014-08-06 08:00:00', date_add(@d, interval +13 hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution for you.

```
    <?php
    $time='10:45';
    $timenew='13:35';
    $a=substr($time,0,2);
    $b=substr($time,3,2);
    $c=substr($timenew,0,2);
    $d=substr($timenew,3,2);
    $m=$a+$c;
    $s=$b+$d;
    if($s>=60)
    {
     $s=$s-60;
     $m++;
    }
    if($m>=24)
    {
     $m=$m-24;
    }
    $n=$m.":".$s;
    echo "$time <br>";
    echo "$timenew <br>";
    echo "New Time=$n";
    ?>
```

**This gives Exact result**

Answer (score -1):

You should convert your column to a time type column (see documentation here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html).

This will simplify things greatly for you in terms of adding time values together, because you can then use `ADDTIME()` function to do what you want (see documentation here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime).